# Validate if a certificate is installed and trusted on osx through terminal

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate, keychain

I can validate if a certificate exists in keychain by using the command

```
security find-certificate -c "Certificate Name" -a
```

But I am trying to see the trust settings of a particular certificate. Mainly, is it trusted and has it expired?

I am unsure which command can do this. I have tried the `security verify-cert` command but this just outputs `...certificate verification successful.` without any details.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer unclear and had to do some additional research.

To verify if the certificate is installed the following command can be used.

```
security verify-cert -c ./certificate.crt
```

The verify-cert man page can be found here: https://ss64.com/osx/security-cert-verify.html

The following is a small bash snippet to check if the certificate is installed, if it is not, add it.

```
# Add the certificate to the macos trust store
security verify-cert -c ./certificate.crt > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "Adding certificate to trust store ..."
    security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ./certificate.crt
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok it turns out `security verify-cert` was the correct command. For a trusted cert this returns `...certificate verification successful.`.

For an untrusted cert this returns `SecTrustEvaluate result: kSecTrustResultDeny`.